# Deploy archives and dependencies to different folders in Maven

Tags: maven-2

I have a multi-module maven project. Currently when building project I want to copy archives to different folders. Third party archives copied in a folder named lib and application archive copied to bin folder. How we do it in Maven?

Answer (score 0):

you can try simple method - copy task in maven
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html
nice official guide btw.

also you can use ant plug-in for maven if you got plenty of old complex script